# Deriving Z-score values for given field using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, statistics

I have a shapefile with an attribute field with a range of numerical values.

How do I derive z-score values for this field using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74098/calculating-z-scores-in-arc and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the steps for calculating Z-Scores in ArcGIS, in this case I have included some screen captures of calculating Z-scores for a field named SourceData.

1. Open up the attribute table and right click on the field header for SourceData and select Statistics from the pop up menu.
   [image]
2. Record the values for Mean and Standard Deviation.  In this case the Mean is 565.43 and the Standard Deviation is 1954.39.
3. Create a new field to store the Z-scores, make sure that this field is a Double.
4. Right click on the field header of the new field you created in step 3.
5. The formula for Z-Scores is SourceData - Mean / Standard Deviation.  Here's what it looks like the Formula Calculator (Note the parenthesis around the first part of the formula):
   [image]
6. You can check your results by running Statistics on the zscore field.  A Z-score will have a mean of zero and a standard deviation of one.
   [image]

Comment: Can you think of anyway to make a standard python script for this to be used in field calculator? I am not able to get the mean and SD values of a field using python in the calculator.

Comment: Made it myself, was not that hard, here is link to the script: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fgx3e4l7pq02pd7/Zscore.py?dl=0

Comment: Can I also have the script, please?

Comment: It would have been better to include that script as an answer