# Calculate z score into new field in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator

I'm trying to calculate z scores for a given column. I am working with a shapefile, that contains fields like percent poverty, percent tree canopy and temperature. My ultimate goal is to add new columns and then calculate z scores for each these fields.

I can calculate a single z score using the procedure described in 
[Deriving Z-score values for given field using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101356/how-to-derive-z-score-values-for-a-given-field)

However, this is something that I'll be doing a lot of times for different geographies and fields. I'd like to be able to run the process in ModelBuilder. I'm not sure if I should create a new tool, or if I can write a script within the "Calculate Field" tool. My Python is not so great, so I'm struggling to make either approach work.

I recognize that this question is similar to [Calculating Z-scores using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74098/calculating-z-scores-in-arc), but I'm not sure how to convert the responses in that post, which are for a raster dataset, to what I'm working on.

So, does anyone know of a pre-existing tool to do this, or is someone willing to offer up some code to make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating Z-scores in Arc](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74098/calculating-z-scores-in-arc)

Comment: You can use Summary Statistics with vector data to get your Mean and SD for your three fields.  Then you can add other fields and calculate z scores on the statistics results.  All of that can be incorporated in Modelbuilder or Python.

Comment: Summary statistics is definitely helpful, but how can I link the results from that table into the calculate fields function? Again, I am a wee babe in the ways of Python.